# AngularJS FullCalendar - Change month on click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

### Issue

---

I have a set of buttons on my application which are different months of the year. When the user clicks on them the Calendar should change to that month and also update the label above it.

I have had an attempt at this (*which you will see from the code below*) but I really stuck on how to achieve my goal. It would be great if you guys could help me out on the best way to write my code for this and also how to code this issue.

### Code

---

So as you can see I have a list of buttons and these are the different months of the year (*Ignore the inline code i know it needs to be moved :P*) I have added 3 buttons as you don't need to see them all they are all the same. I have also added the label into this code:

```
<div class="col-lg-2" ng-controller="monthSelection" style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #E7E7E7; padding-bottom: 20px;">
         <div class="col-lg-12 text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">
             <span style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 20px;">April 2016</span>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <button style="border: none; background-color: #ffd47f; border-radius: 5px; height: 30px; width: 100%;" ng-click="JanClick()>Jan</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <button style="border: none; background-color: #ffd47f; border-radius: 5px; height: 30px; width: 100%;">Feb</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <button style="border: none; background-color: #ffd47f; border-radius: 5px; height: 30px; width: 100%;">Mar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code which creates the Calendar:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div ng-controller="aceTracker">
            <div ng-model="eventSources" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in my controller I tried to add something like this (*it didn't work*):

```
app.controller('monthSelection', function ($scope) {
    $scope.JanClick = function () {
        $scope.calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', 2012, 11);
    }
});
```

### Conclusion

---

How can I get the Calendar to change to the correct month as well as the label above the Calendar? What is the best way to write my code to reduce the code as much as possible?

Comment: A plunker would be helpful. You are missing a closing `"` after `ng-click="JanClick()`, which might be throwing a wrench in things. One approach might be to have an array of month objects like `{ name: 'Jan', monthIndex: 0}`, `{ name: 'Feb', monthIndex: 1}`, and so on, and ng-repeat through them to create the buttons in your html. Then your `ng-click` function could be `setMonth(month)`, which in your controller would be `$scope.setMonth = function (month) { $scope.calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', 2012, month.monthIndex); };`.

Comment: @BennettAdams Thanks for your response. I was wondering, my controller code where i say `$scope.calendar.fullCalendar` is this correct with the code for my calendar?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't see a reference to `calendar` or `fullCalendar` anywhere in your template that is scoped to the `monthSelection` controller. If you're using the `monthSelection` controller to control the display of a calendar that is scoped to a different controller, it won't work unless you have a) some kind of service handling the data between the controllers, or b) messages passed from one controller to the other via a `$rootScope.$broadcast` in the `monthSelection` controller and a `$scope.$on` listener in the calendar display controller. Again, a plunker would be nice :)